# Missing letters of database objects being returned in DBI SQL Server ODBC connection

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, freetds, r-dbi

Unfortunately, I will not be able to create a good repro for this issue without sharing confidential creds to the database I am having issues with. Hopefully I have enough information below to flag any obvious problems that ODBC experts will understand.

**Background**

I am running a MacBook Pro with the following specs:

```
  Model Name:       MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro15,1
  Processor Name:   6-Core Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.6 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    6
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 9 MB
  Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled
  Memory:   32 GB
  Boot ROM Version: 1037.0.78.0.0 (iBridge: 17.16.10572.0.0,0)
```

My ODBC connection is set using FreeTDS as specified [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Mac-OSX).

The relevant portion of `freetds.conf` is as follows:

```
# The POC SQL Server
[POC]
host = 172.22.238.154
port = 1433
tds version = 7.3
```

My `odbcinst.ini` file is as follows:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS Driver for Linux & SQL Server 
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount=1
```

My `odbc.ini` file is specified as follows:

```
[POC]
Description         = Connecton to Partners for our children SQL Server 
Driver              = FreeTDS
Servername          = POC
```

I am trying to make a connection to a SQL Server 2012 database (via VPN) using the following connection information in R:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc()
                  ,dsn = "POC"
                  ,uid = Sys.getenv("MSSQL_UN")
                  ,database = "CA_ODS"
                  ,pwd = Sys.getenv("MSSQL_PW"))
```

This generates the following connection object:

```
> con
  <OdbcConnection> POC2
  Database: CA_ODS
  Microsoft SQL Server Version: 11.00.7001
```

In general, this connection works as expected. I can query the database using `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select * from MyTable")`, `dplyr::tbl(con, MyTable)`, etc. without issue.

**Problem**

RStudio, however, is only displaying every other letter of the database objects, and truncating the object names after the first several letters. The following screenshot should illustrate the issue well:

[image]

The database I am trying to connect to is called `CA_ODS`. However, the RStudio object browser is only displaying every other letter of the database name (i.e. the DB is listed as `C_D`).

This does not appear to be limited to RStudio *per se* either. While the results of the actual database queries work fine as described above, the returned names from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` appear to match the information in the object browser. Below, when run directly from SQL Server Management Studio, the returned `TABLE_CATALOG` is `CA_ODS`, `TABLE_SCHEMA` is `ndacan`, etc. When run via the DB connection, however, I get the following.

```
> DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE 
TABLE_SCHEMA='ndacan'")
   TABLE_CATALOG TABLE_SCHEMA      TABLE_NAME TABLE_TYPE
1            C_D          naa            f21v BASE TABLE
```

**Question**

Any suggestions as to how I can respecify my ODBC connection in R or in my FreeTDS configs to get the full name of database objects returned?

Comment: Likely related: https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/283. My guess is that your macos is running R-3.6. It appears that two things have worked for some people: (1) downgrading to R-3.5.3; and (2) reinstalling the `odbc` package [**from source**](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/283#issuecomment-545469314) (not a CRAN binary).

Comment: @r2evans This fixed it for me (i.e. `install.packages("odbc", type = 'source')`)

Comment: If you want to provide an answer, I'll accept it. Unrelated (I was experiencing this issue before upgrading to Catalina, but Catalina appears to have jacked with XCode) - I needed to reinstall XCode before I could get `odbc` to install from source. `xcode-select --install` should do the trick for XCode

Comment: I believe you answering yourself (with the steps you took) would be more credible: I don't have macos and was only forwarding a third-party conversation. You, on the other hand, did a little bit more. In addition to self-answering, it would likely be helpful to include the extra Xcode steps you took in a comment on the original issue (https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/283), as they are still figuring this one out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As noted in @r2evans comments, this appears to be an issue with `odbc`, running in R 3.6.0, on a Mac.

In general, it appears that this can be fixed by reinstalling `odbc` from source `install.packages("odbc", type = 'source')`.

As also noted in the comments, I had recently upgraded my Mac to Catalina. *Prior* to installing `odbc` from source I needed to first reinstall XCode using `xcode-select --install` from my terminal.

As can be seen in the screen capture below, I am now getting the full object names displayed from the `odbc` connection.

[image]

Comment: thanks, this really helped me! (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58777915/truncation-of-database-name-and-columns-while-connecting-to-sql-database-from-r/58788514#58788514)

Comment: this is happening to me with odbc, MSSQL Driver 17, running on R 4.3.1, fresh install, upgraded from 4.2.2. I tried your solution of installing odbc from source and now RStudio  crashes out any time i try to use odbc to get a connection. I had to remove odbc and reinstall NOT from source to avoid the crash but still getting bad query results.