# Truncation of database name and columns while connecting to SQL database from R

Tags: r, odbc

I am on macOS Catalina (Version 10.15.1), running R 3.5.0. I am running SQL server on Docker locally. For connecting to the server, I am using `odbc`:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), 
                   Driver = "Simba SQL Server ODBC Driver", 
                   Server = "localhost", 
                   UID = 'SA',
                   PWD  = 'XXXXXXXX',
                   database = dbname)
```

I am able to connect to the server, however the names of all the databases therein are getting truncated to just the first letter as shown here:

[image]

Subsequently all the character columns are also showing only the first letter.

[image]

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249788/rodbc-and-microsoft-sql-server-truncating-long-character-strings?rq=1), but just can't figure out why this is happening. For starters, the names of the databases itself, as shown in the RStudio Connections pane, are getting truncated.

I am able to connect to the databases using Azure Data Studio and see all the columns correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58550163/missing-letters-of-database-objects-being-returned-in-dbi-sql-server-odbc-connec) and turns out this was exactly what I was facing. Followed the steps mentioned here to resolve the issue.